# Combining timeout and cpulimit

Tags: timeout

I have a situation where a process that hangs under certain circumstances or runs for too long should be killed. Also I don't want the process to take 100% of the CPU time. I am thinking that I should combine `cpulimit` and `timeout`.

I can get each command to work separately but not together:

```
cpulimit -l 20 -- /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --headless --convert-to pdf broken.docx

timeout -k 6 -s 15 6s /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --headless --convert-to pdf broken.docx
```

I would like to do something like:

```
cpulimit -l 20 -- | timeout -k 6 -s 15 6s /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --headless --convert-to pdf broken.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to run the `timeout` command as argument of the `cpulimit`:

```
cpulimit -l 20 -- timeout -k 6 -s 15 6s /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --headless --convert-to pdf broken.docx
```

Note that this is exactly like your last example but without the pipe `|` (the pipe chains the output of the first process with the input of the second that is not what you want here).

Comment: Problem with this solution is that only the `timeout`command has any effect. `cpulimit` is ignored.

Comment: swapping timeout and cpulimit may fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `nice` with `timeout` instead. One problem with `cpulimit` and `timeout` combo was that `soffice.bin`spawned several processes and the parent process somehow wasn't affected.

That solved my problem.

Also `nice` give the process the possibility to use 100% of the CPU if no other processes are running instead of a hard cap on the resources.

`nice timeout -k 5 6s /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --headless --convert-to pdf broken.docx`